# .net treeview ajax onclick

Tags: .net, ajax, treeview

This is my treeview:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div style="width:100%;height:30px;float:left;line-height:30px;">
    <asp:Label Text="Testo" runat="server" ID="tree_node" />
</div>

<div style="width:100%;height:400px;">
    <div style="width:300px;float:left;">
        <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged"></asp:TreeView>
    </div>
</div>

<Asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UP2">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="image" Width="200" Height="200" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TreeView1" EventName="selectedNodeChanged" />
    </Triggers>

</Asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and this is the onselectmethod:

```
protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tree_node.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value;
    image.ImageUrl = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value;

}
```

without updatepanel work but with the postback, what I need is to refresh image and label without the postback, so without the refresh of the page, where is the error?

Comment: Controls outside the contentTemplate of the uupdate panel won't be included in asynchronous calls

Comment: Ok for the label but the image isn't update to the correct image, so i think there is some other problem!

Comment: I'm pretty sure controls specified in the Triggers should be within the ContentTemplate, not sure what happens when you specify a control outside of the template, probably behavior like you're seeing.

Comment: I put all inside the update panel and trhough xhr I see that my elements the response is correct, but the image and label is not refresh.